# Proving $f(x) = x^5$ is not uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, uniform-continuity

Is this line of reasoning legitimate?

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x) = x^5$. $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

Suppose it were. Fix $\epsilon>0$ and the associated $\delta$, and choose $x,~ y>0, ~x>y$, st $|x-y|< \delta$.

Then, $|x-y|<\delta \Rightarrow |x^5 - y^5|<\epsilon ~\forall x, y$

Fix $|x-y| = C$. Then,

$$|x^5 - y^5| = |x-y||x^4 + x^3y + x^2y^2 + xy^3 + y^4|= $$

$$C|x^4 + x^3y + x^2y^2 + xy^3 + y^4|<\epsilon$$.

This is valid for all $x, y$ sufficiently close, but because the left hand side increases monotonically, it can be made arbitrarily large while keeping $|x-y|<\delta$, so this is a contradiction. Therefore f is not uniformly continuous.

I'm pretty sure this is logically sound *kinda* and I think my intuition (that because f is increasing increasingly fast without bound, no set of fixed-sized intervals in the domain map to a set of bounded intervals in the image) but I think I can get away with a lot less. Any advice?

Comment: One interesting way to verify non-uniform continuity is to note that if $f$ is uniformly continuous on its domain, $\{s_n\}$ and $\{t_n\}$ are sequences in the domain, and $|s_n - t_n| \to 0$, then $|f(s_n) - f(t_n)| \to 0$.

Try that out with $s_n = n$ and $t_n = n + \frac 1n$.

Comment: There is nothing like monotonically increasing in two variables. I suggest adding $x,y \gt 0$ then left side will be tending to infinity when both $x,y \to \infty$. Then it looks fine.

Comment: @VikrantDesai it says $x,y>0$

Comment: Kill me now man! You have done then. It is 'increasing' then.

Comment: Your proof is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way of arguing is as follows:

Suppose it were, then for every $\epsilon$, there exists a $\delta$ for which $|x - y| < \delta \implies |x^5 - y^5| < \epsilon$

However, consider $\epsilon = 1$; if such $\delta$ existed and $y = x + \frac{\delta}{2}$, we would find that

$$|x^5 - (x + \frac{\delta}{2})^5| < 1$$

for every real $x$; however, this a clear contradiction, since we can  choose $x$ large.

Comment: I guess I'm worried that this will be insufficiently transparent. That's the difficulty for me; I'm never clear what can be stated without proof; I assume this is an intuition that comes with time. Is what I wrote correct, if unnecessarily long?

Comment: You didn't answer my question. I asked if my proof was legit; you provided an alternate proof. That's not what I asked for.

Answer (score 0):

This argument works for any function with an unbounded derivative.
Since $f'(x) >M$ for any $M>0$,
$f(x+h)-f(x)>Mh$
which contradicts uniform continuity
for large enough $M$.

Comment: That's helpful for the future, but derivatives aren't admitted in this part of the course.

Answer (score -1):

Take , $\displaystyle x=\frac{\delta}{2}+\frac{1}{(\delta)^{1/4}}$ and $\displaystyle y=\frac{1}{(\delta)^{1/4}}$. Then , $\displaystyle |x-y|=\frac{\delta}{2}<\delta$.

But , $|f(x)-f(y)|>5/2$.

**Note :** Any function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=x^n$ is NOT uniformly continuous  for $n>1$.

Comment: I didn't ask you for a different proof. I asked for a critique of mine. Saying "your proof is wrong" doesn't help, and doesn't answer the question.